# Sum of date difference in big query in days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum, distinct, datediff

I want to sum date difference in days from `PostionEndDate` and `PostionStartDate`. I have a lot of duplication in my table so in order to get rid of duplication first we need to create a unique ID say combination of `PositionID`, `PositionStartDate` and `PositionEndDate` and then sum a distinct unique ID date difference. I been able to create below code using `Distinct PostionID`, however I am not been able to include concat unique ID value. Any input would be helpful.

```
Sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PositionName IN ('Department Manager','Manager - Large Format','Team Manager') 
THEN CASE WHEN MovementMethodTo = 'TERMINATION' THEN DATE_DIFF(LastDayAtWork, PositionStartDate, DAY) ELSE DATE_DIFF(IF(PositionEndDate = '9999-12-31', CURRENT_DATE(), PositionEndDate),
PositionStartDate, DAY) END ELSE NULL END) AS SM_TenureInMonths
```

The problem with my code same PositionID is same however Start date and end date are different.